# Как сделать, что бы при переходе кода с одной строки на вторую прошло N времени

Tags: c#, unity3d

Допустим есть 2 строки кода :

```
i = 5;
//...
i = 2;
```

Как сделать, что бы переход между i = 5; и i = 2; длился N секунд. "Таймер" можно сказать. Реализую в Unity3D.

Comment: Учите матчасть, уважаемый.
В Вашем случае необходимо использовать [корутины/сопрограммы](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Coroutines.html) и [yield return new WaitForSeconds(X)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментарии выше я указал ссылки, с которыми настоятельно советую ознакомиться для понимания нижеприведенного кода.

В некоем методе (назовем его "Method") вызываем корутину "DoWithWait", в которой переменной присваиваем значение 5, затем ожидаем 10 сек. и присваиваем значение 2:

```
private void Method()
{
    StartCoroutine( DoWithWait() );
}

private IEnumerator DoWithWait()
{
    i = 5;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10.0f);
    i = 2;
}
```

Comment: А нельзя как-нибудь по другому? Я не могу свой код запихнуть в корутину. У меня проверка на нажатие клавиши Space для прыжка. Но если я запихну в корутину, я не смогу прыгать постоянно

Comment: Тогда, возможно, следует пересмотреть логику анимации и переделать так, что бы либо таймер был не нужен, либо что бы прыжок был доступен и в корутине...

Comment: На своих диких костылях впихнул прыжек в корутину. Спасибо за ответ.